# How to get text from TextInput in a special container [Nokia Qt Qml]

Tags: c++, symbian

I'm trying to program a sudoku game on Symbian using Qt Creator.

My sudoku game is made with a `Grid` (QML element) of 9 x 9 rectangles in which there are some  `TextInput` elements limited to one character (the number).
If its needed, I can paste the code here.

I don't know how I can get all values from the sudoku grid into a single container, so that I can send it to C++ code in order to process the values, and to determine if the player has won or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the values of each TextInput element.

I hope you created an array of TextInput so you could use loop to obtain them.
If not then read this: [How to make an Array of Widgets](http://www.jwdougherty.com/content/qt-creating-array-widgets)

You can also check [How to access your child widgets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq03-big-brother.html) at runtime.

Comment: Hi,
I understand the concept. But the example you gave me is C++. I know how to do this using c++. I have a QML file in which is designed my sudoku game. How can i create an array of TextInput using QML ?
How can i get values in every TextInput of sudoku game when i press button "Finished" for example ?
I can paste here, or send  the qml file.
Thank's

Comment: For these reasons I dont use QML, but create the interface directly in c++.
I think that it should be possible to get the array of controls during runtime - http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq03-big-brother.html